# delete all files except one or two files (files/sub directory files) using .bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch Scripting. The requirement is, Directory contains folders with sub folders and files. Need to delete all files except two files, which contains the extension like .css .html. Don't know about batch(.bat) Scripting. Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: What have you tried, what do you have troubles with? Please learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this which will loop through all directories from where the batch file is placed and delete files that don't match the desired extension

```
@echo off
echo.

REM loop through files
for /r %%f in (*) do call :myFunc %%f
goto End

REM function to check files
:myFunc
set file=%1
set delete=TRUE
REM don't delete the batch script (replace with your batch script name)
if not "%file%"=="%file:batchscriptname.bat=%" set delete=FALSE
REM don't delete .html files
if not "%file%"=="%file:.html=%" set delete=FALSE
REM don't delete .css files
if not "%file%"=="%file:.css=%" set delete=FALSE
REM execute the delete
if "%delete%"=="TRUE" echo %file%
goto :eof

:End
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
for / "delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /B/S/A-d X:\startfolder\* ^|findstr /i /v "\.css$ \.html$" '
) Do echo Del "%%~fA"
```

If the output looks right, remove the echo in front of del.